# implicit equation for covering a $3\times{n}$ face with $2\times{1}$ mosaics with recursion solution?

Tags: recursive-algorithms

This is my university homework. I was on it for a day but I couldn't solve the problem.
I found a implicitness solution for this problem:

$f(2)=3$

$f(4)=11$

$f(n)=3f(n-2)+2f(n-4)$

I thought that it should be true but when I found an implicitness solution there was difference between implicit and explicit answers. Can anybody please suggest a good strategy for finding implicit answer for this types of questions?

Comment: I don't understand how you're using the terms "implicit solution" and "explicit solution". I would have thought that the recursion relation is an implicit defnition of the function $f$, and the closed form derivable from it is an explicit definition. But by "implicit solution" you seem to be referring to a third form? What kind of form is this?

Comment: i used implicit for terms like that i wrote in my post and explicit for a single term for example a0(k0)^n

Comment: It sounds like what you mean by implicit is what's traditionally called a 'recurrence relation'.

Comment: There's an extensive and detailed solution of this exact problem in the "Generating Functions" chapter of *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, around page 343.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. This is a good example of why the question should be self-contained and not rely on the title. Because you hadn't stated the problem in the body of the question, I thought that "this problem" referred to the problem following it, so I concluded that "implicitness solution" must be referring to something else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you’re trying to find a recurrence (and perhaps also a closed form) for the number of ways to tile a $3\times n$ checkerboard with $2\times 1$ dominoes. Clearly this is possible only when $n$ is even, and I agree that $f(2)=3$ and $f(4)=11$. Now let’s consider $f(2n)$ for some $n>2$. For $a\le k<n$ I’ll say that a tiling of $3\times(2n)$ *splits* at $2k$ if it is formed of a tiling of $3\times(2k)$ followed by a tiling of $3\times(2n-2k)$. Your term $3f(2n-2)$ counts the tilings of $3\times(2n)$ that split at $2n-2$, and your term $2f(2n-4)$ counts those that split at $2n-4$ but **not** at $2n-2$. However, these are not the only possibilities. Here’s a tiling of $3\times 6$ that doesn’t split:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
1&1&2&2&3&3\\ \hline
4&5&5&6&6&7\\ \hline
4&8&8&9&9&7\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Squares with the same number are covered by a single domino. This same idea can be extended indefinitely:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
1&1&2&2&3&3&4&4&5&5\\ \hline
6&7&7&8&8&9&9&10&10&11\\ \hline
6&12&12&13&13&14&14&15&15&11\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

In each case the top row of dominoes prevents a split at any odd-numbered position, and the bottom two rows prevent a split at any even-numbered position. Thus, you won’t be able to set up a simple recurrence of the kind that you had in mind.

There is a way to derive a closed form using generating functions; it’s discussed in detail in Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, pp. 325-7 and pp. 343-4. With a bit of work it can be turned into a derivation of a recurrence as well, though not a very nice one.

**Added:** Let $u_n=f(2n)$. Let $v_n$ be the number of tilings of a $3\times(2n+1)$ board that’s missing its lower left corner square; this is clearly also the number of tilings of a $3\times(2n+1)$ board that’s missing its upper left corner square. Every tiling of $3\times(2n)$ with $n>0$ begins in one of three ways:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
1&\\ \hline
1&\\ \hline
2&2\\ \hline
\end{array}\quad\text{or}\quad
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
1&1\\ \hline
2&\\ \hline
2\\ \hline
\end{array}\quad\text{or}\quad
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
1&1\\ \hline
2&2\\ \hline
3&3\\ \hline
\end{array}\;.
$$

The first must be followed by a tiling of a $3\times(2n-1)$ board that’s missing its lower left square; the second must be followed by a tiling of a $3\times(2n-1)$ board that’s missing its upper left square; and the last must be followed by a tiling of a $3\times(2n-2)$ board. Thus, $$u_n=2v_{n-1}+u_{n-1}\;.$$

Every tiling of a $3\times(2n+1)$ board that’s missing its lower left square must begin with

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
1&\;\\ \hline
1&\\ \hline
&\\ \hline
\end{array}\quad\text{or}\quad
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
1&1\\ \hline
2&2\\ \hline
&3&3\\ \hline
\end{array}\;;\tag{1}
$$

the first of these will be followed by a tiling of $3\times(2n)$, and the second by a tiling of a $3\times(2n-1)$ board that’s missing its lower left square. Thus, $$v_n=u_n+v_{n-1}\;.$$ Turning the pictures upside-down shows that this recurrence also holds for $v_n$ considered as the number of tilings of a $3\times(2n+1)$ board with the upper left square missing. Thus, we have the system

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
u_n&=u_{n-1}+2v_{n-1}\\
v_n&=v_{n-1}+u_n\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
u_n&=u_{n-1}+2v_{n-1}\\
&=u_{n-1}+2(v_{n-2}+u_{n-1})\\
&=3u_{n-1}+2v_{n-2}\\
&=3u_{n-1}+2(v_{n-3}+u_{n-2})\\
&=3u_{n-1}+2u_{n-2}+2v_{n-3}\\
&\;\vdots\\
&=3u_{n-1}+2(u_{n-2}+u_{n-3}+\ldots+u_1)+2v_0\\
&=2+u_{n-1}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}u_k\;,
\end{align*}$$

since $v_0=1$ (represented by the first picture in $(1)$). If we set $u_0=1$, this simplifies to $$u_n=u_{n-1}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k\;.\tag{2}$$ To get anything nicer than this, you really want to use generating functions.

**Added<sub>2</sub>:** As Steven Stadnicki pointed out in comments, $(2)$ allows us to get a nice recurrence very easily:

$$\begin{align*}
u_n-u_{n-1}&=\left(u_{n-1}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k\right)-\left(u_{n-2}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}u_k\right)\\
&=u_{n-1}+2u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}\\
&=3u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $$u_n=4u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}\;.\tag{3}$$

From $(3)$ we get the auxiliary equation $x^2-4x+1=0$, with roots $$\frac{4\pm\sqrt{12}}2=2\pm\sqrt3\;;$$ let $\alpha=2+\sqrt3$ and $\beta=2-\sqrt3$. Then $u_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$ for suitable $A$ and $B$. Setting $n=0$ and $n=1$ yields $1=u_0=A+B$ and $3=u_1=A\alpha+B\beta$, respectively. The solution to this system is $$A=\frac{3+\sqrt3}6=\frac1{3-\sqrt3},~B=\frac{3-\sqrt3}6=\frac1{3+\sqrt3}\;,$$ so

$$u_n=\frac{(2+\sqrt3)^n}{3-\sqrt3}+\frac{(2-\sqrt3)^n}{3+\sqrt3}\;.\tag{4}$$

Finally, $\dfrac{(2-\sqrt3)^n}{3+\sqrt3}<\dfrac12$ for $n\ge 0$, so $$f(2n)=u_n=\left\lfloor\frac{(2+\sqrt3)^n}{3-\sqrt3}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;,$$ the integer nearest $\dfrac{(2+\sqrt3)^n}{3-\sqrt3}$, for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: Out of curiosity (somehow I've managed to never read _Concrete Mathematics_!), does the generating function approach work via intertwined recurrence relations among generating functions for each of the 'partial' cases?  (e.g., '$t_{0,1,0}(n) =$ number of 3xn tilings with a single non-domino cell at (n, 2)', '$t_{0,1,1}(n) =$ number of 3xn tilings with two non-domino cells at (n,2) and (n,3)', etc?)

Comment: @Steven: It does indeed. In fact, I’m about to add the derivation of the recurrences needed to get the generating function(s) nicely, and you’ll see.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  Incidentally, from the last expression there's a pretty straightforward derivation of a more explicit recurrence: $u_n-u_{n-1} = (u_{n-1}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k)-(u_{n-2}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}u_k) = u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}+2u_{n-1}$ since the sums almost completely cancel, so $u_n = 4u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}$ and the usual characteristic methods should apply...

Comment: @Steven: You’re right; I’m so used to the other approach these days that I completely missed that. The answer’s getting a bit long, but that’s so easy that I’ll go ahead and finish it off. Thanks!

Comment: thanks Brian for your complete and step by step solution.i learned it good.also i will plan to read the materials that you suggested

Comment: +1, nice treatment and nice pictures! However you can get the characteristic values more directly without going through the summation, either by eliminating one of $u$ and $v$ in favour of the other or by writing

$$
\begin{align*}
u_n&=u_{n-1}+2v_{n-1}\\
v_n&=v_{n-1}+u_n
\end{align*}
$$

as

$$
\pmatrix{u_n\\v_n}
=
\pmatrix{1&2\\1&3}
\pmatrix{u_{n-1}\\v_{n-1}}
$$

(after substituting the first equation into the second) and finding the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If we define $m=\frac {n-2}2$ your recurrence becomes $f(m)=3f(m-1)+2f(m-2), f(0)=3, f(1)=11$.  Using the standard technique of assuming a power law solution, the roots are $\frac {3 \pm \sqrt{17}}2$ and the solution is $f(m)=\left(\frac 32 + \frac {11}{\sqrt {17}}\right)\left(\frac {3 + \sqrt{17}}2\right)^m+\left(\frac 32 - \frac {11}{\sqrt {17}}\right)\left(\frac {3 - \sqrt{17}}2\right)^m$